# Acceso de terceros al código de mi app web en flask/python

Tags: html, python, web, flask, framework

Tengo una duda con lo siguiente, tengo desarrollada una app web en Python con el framework Flask, esta la llevaré a producción y mi duda es si un tercero puede acceder a mi código en Python de alguna forma? si es posible esto, cómo puedo proteger el código de este acceso?

Comment: tu aplicacion correra dentro de un servidor. Si alguien ingresa al servidor podra ver tu codigo fuente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si accede directamente al servidor si podrá, pero no a través de los html entregados, ya que estos solo se muestran como html puro y no como jinjaHTML.